# If a computer has an Intel processor does it mean that it is an x86 machine?

Tags: assembly, cpu, intel, instruction-set, opcode

- Is it true that every machine that has an Intel CPU is an x86 machine?
- Considering that all Intel CPU are backward compatible does it mean that every x86 machine is able to run Intel CPUs instruction sets?

Comment: obviously no, Intel has manufactured lots of different architectures like Itanium, i860, i960...

Comment: the current 64 bit instruction set is called amd64 for a reason, it wasnt intel that developed it. so terms like intel cpu instruction set make even less sense in the small x86 subset of the intel processor family

Answer (score 5):

> Is it true that every machine that has an Intel CPU is an x86 machine?

No! Although *"Intel CPU"* is widely used that way, it's actually not a correct way to refer to x86 CPUs. Nowadays the only Intel CPUs you can buy are x86(-64), but historically Intel has produced CPUs in various different architectures like Itanium, i860, i960, iAPX 432, ARM (yes, Intel produced [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XScale) [CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StrongARM))... and even the 4004, 8008, 8080, 8048, 8051, MCS-96... Neither of them are binary compatible with each other, except for a few Itanium CPUs that contain an x86 core inside. There are also [research architectures from Intel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Tera-Scale) but you can't buy them

You may even see non-x86 CPUs from Intel in the not-so-distant future, because Intel is [one of the biggest members of RISC-V](https://riscv.org/blog/2022/02/intel-corporation-makes-deep-investment-in-risc-v-community-to-accelerate-innovation-in-open-computing/) and it's already producing RISC-V CPUs although currently [for SiFive](https://riscv.org/news/2021/06/intel-will-offer-sifive-risc-v-cpus-on-7nm-plans-own-dev-platform-joel-hruska-extremetech/) and not its own design yet

> Considering that all Intel CPU are backward compatible does it mean that every x86 machine is able to run Intel CPUs instruction sets?

There are no such things as *"Intel CPU instruction set"* because as said, there are so many different ISAs from Intel. So it should be read as "*Considering that **x86** CPUs are backward compatible, all current x86 CPUs can run all 16, 32 and 64-bit x86 instruction sets"*. Note that x86-64 was invented by AMD and licensed back to Intel so *every x86 machine is able to run Intel CPUs instruction sets* is also wrong in many ways

However that may soon (or not) be changed. Intel already announced that it'll remove the CSM module for BIOS compatibility completely so it'll lose the ability to run some 16-bit OSes natively, and it's possible that they'll also remove real mode and some instructions in that mode

Comment: While you are technically right, "Intel CPU" is widely recognized as a synonym for "x86 CPU". I think would be better to add the commonly intended meaning at the start of the question and then explain that it is a misnomer. BTW, when you say that Intel will remove the CSM, it means that the FSP (or whatever it is) Intel gives to the manufacturer won't contain 16-bit code for easily implementing the legacy BIOS interrupt services? I thought that booting an OS and exposing these services was mostly done by the OEM. Anyway, can't they switch back and forth between real-long mode and reuse UEFI?

Comment: @MargaretBloom I don't know the details, haven't checked that. But what I mean is the ability to boot those OSes directly will be removed. And it may be possible that in the future some x86-16 support will also be removed, for example real mode and some unused instructions

Answer (score 0):

Currently I believe so. However, there was the Itanium architecture that was  not x86 that Intel had released for a while (currently discontinued).